# Github pages - how to share the private key and the passphrase to decrypt data?

Tags: javascript, github-pages, gnupg, static-site

I want to create a website and share it with my family, and only my family.
To do this, I created a new repository on github and I created a github pages on it. I created gpg keys to encrypt the data and I put them on github. I found the code to decrypt the data with OpenGPG and I see that it needs the private key and the passphrase.

My question is can I store the private key on github and share the passphrase with my family by email? I suppose that is not a good idea to store the private key on github... but is there a different way to do this ?

Also, does the passphrase encrypt the keys? I am a little lost...

Thanks for your help!
MN

Comment: I'm afraid that you will lose you're time developing something very tricky to master like authentication.You can clearly delegate this to a provider such as netlify. Publishing you site is made in minutes, just like setting up authentication : https://www.netlify.com/docs/identity/